# POST Request via SSJS - Authorisation Types

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, post

I am working on sending an outbound POST request and haven't been able to send one to my end point url. I'm receiving a Status Code 500 indicating that this is an SSJS issue however, upon closer inspection and replacing the end point url and payload with one required to generate a Marketing Cloud Access Token which was successful.

The authentication type for this request is a HTTP Signature which is a hashed based method using a shared secret key. I haven't seen any examples other than Bearer and API key authentication and was wondering if anyone knew if there were limitations to the authentication types that can be used when sending a POST request via SSJS?

Comment: If you're trying to sign your requests using HMAC-SHA, this isn't possible using AMPScript or SSJS.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to sign using HMAC-SHA and the request is not appearing to execute in SSJS. Thanks for the reply!